# Is there a way to bet more than 9999 medals?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In the coliseum, you can bet on monster fights.

With the results of your bets, you can get an engine that does not consume gas (giving infinite gas)

Thing is, that engine is 3.7 million medals (from memory, can't see the exact number), so even if you bet and win the max amount every time, it's gonna be a while. The counter only has 4 digits, making the max bet 9999 medals.

Is there a way to upgrade and make bigger bets and advance faster?

Comment: Useful information: When you end the game, and get the Type F, it comes with that infinite engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There's no way to bet more than 9999 medals at a time.**
You simply have to grind through the colosseum a lot in order to get the rewards you want.

Comment: Well, F this, won't be sitting there for hours :p

Comment: to save a 10 gil every few hours

Comment: yeah unfortunately the late game is pretty grindy